# Last fields are lost in POST

Tags: php, symfony, http, post, symfony-forms

I'm extending an Web Application that has a form with a field that is a List. But this list **CAN HAVE** many value as the user want.

The last field is the `CSRF Token`

```
{{ form_widget(form._token) }}
```

Testing I found that when I add as many field I can the error an CSRF error occurrs int the form:

> The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.

The problem is that for too large info in the form, the `Symfony` controller trunks the information, and do not parse the final of the `POST` request. If I invert the order and set the last field to the list, the list will not be sended complete.

My questions:

- This is a limitation of HTTP protocol?
- If `yes`, there is a good solution to handle this limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely the `max_input_vars` setting in PHP, not Symfony that is truncating your posted data.

Could you post the contents of `phpinfo();`?

Typically you can override this PHP configuration setting per virtual host or server-wide in the php.ini file.

Comment: This field is not set in `php.ini`, there is only the default comented `max_input_vars`.

Comment: The default is `1000`, maybe this is the problem.

Comment: @Victor - Oops, edited my post to reflect the correct configuration setting. Did that resolve it for ya?

Comment: Yes! But the bad news for me is that I should set a limit to this list.Thanks!